# Azure Virtual Desktop deployment. Setting SecurityType to Trusted Launch

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-bicep

I am relatively new to coding and learning Bicep to help me deploy a small AVD environment in my lab. Please be easy with me if I don't provide enough info on the first try... :-)

I am using the same code base as defined here: https://rozemuller.com/avd-automation-cocktail-avd-with-bicep-and-azure-cli/#azure-compute-gallery but I have made some alterations to it as I am trying to create a gen2 Trusted Launch VM to be used instead of a standard SecurityType defined here.

1. I create my initial image version of Windows 11 using Securitytype trusted launch. That all went well. Defined in my BICEP file under

```
resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2023-03-01' = {
  // Security profile properties...
  securityProfile: {
    uefiSettings: {
      secureBootEnabled: true
      vTpmEnabled: true
    }
    securityType: 'TrustedLaunch'
  }
  diagnosticsProfile: {
    bootDiagnostics: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```

I generalise and sysprep the initial image build and then come to running the main.bicep file alongside the parameters to build out the AVD environment using the initial image created previously as the base VM image for my AVDs.

However when it goes through the process of deploying this gallery image, it fails with the error:

The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. (Code: ResourceDeploymentFailure, Target: /subscriptions/2820ff07-405a-49c6-b74b-d78825165e02/resourceGroups/uks-rb81-vdi-avd-hpl-priv-001-01/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/uksbldglbssvgal01/images/uks-img-Windows-desktop-11-gen2-22h2-priv-tl-001/versions/2023.09.26)
The source 'subscriptions/2820ff07-405a-49c6-b74b-d78825165e02/resourceGroups/rg-Win11-template/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/i4xsd3rrtnobm-vm' has security type 'TrustedLaunch' and cannot be used as a source for an image definition with SecurityType feature set to 'None'. (Code: Conflict)

I don't seem to have an errors in the code. I have updated the main.bicep and module deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep with declaring the param in both locations.

```
@description('Security Type')
param securityType string = 'TrustedLaunch'
```

Under the module I have added the param securityType

```
module avdSessionhosts 'Templates/AVD/deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep' = {
  name: 'deploy-avd-sessionhosts'
  scope: resourceGroup
  dependsOn: [
    avdEnvironment
    vnets
  ]
  params: {
    hostpoolName: hostpoolName
    location: location
    securityType: securityType
```

in deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep

```
@description('Security Type')
param securityType string
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? Tearing my hair out at the moment....

Expecting it to use the image from gallery to deploy AVD session hosts with desired configuration.

Comment: Can you share the content of the deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep file please?

Comment: Hi it seems I can't copy the content due to the character limit and I can't attach the file. Is there a known way I can do this in SO?

Comment: In my bicep file in relation to the securityType in the avd-sessionhosts.bicep file I have added the param

@description('Security Type')
param securityType string = 'TrustedLaunch'

and then under the resource vm there is a section under security profile

Comment: resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2023-03-01' = [for i in range(0, rdshNumberOfInstances): {
  name: '${rdshPrefix}${(i + rdshInitialNumber)}-vm'
  location: location
  tags: virtualMachineTags
  identity: {
    type: (aadJoin ? 'SystemAssigned' : 'None')
  }
  properties: {  
    // Set the security type based on the value of the securityType parameter
    securityProfile: {
      securityType: securityType
    }
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: rdshVmSize
    }
    availabilitySet: ((availabilityOption == 'AvailabilitySet') ? vmAvailabilitySetResourceId : null

Comment: The issue is about the image not the VM. The error message saying you cant create an image from a VM with TrustedLaunch if the image doesnt have trusted launch

Comment: in deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep, are you using an image gallery ?

Comment: Just trying to clarify what type of image you are building ? if you could let us know what type of resource are provisioned in the deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep file ? Also you could always upload the file in github and share with us

Comment: Yes I have created a Win 11 enterprise initial image which was a V2, trusted launch etc, that is stored in the image gallery with an image definition, however the definition is still showing the securityType as Standard. I'm not sure how to change this, I can't change in the GUI but would like to be able to achieve this in code. Could it be somewhere in the deploy-shared-image-gallery.bicep that I would need to update?

https://github.com/srozemuller/AVD/blob/1fa198352b23bc4cbc9af45f7094f21baf25e766/Deployment/MintyBreeze/Templates/ComputeGallery/deploy-shared-image-gallery.bicep

Comment: https://github.com/srozemuller/AVD/blob/1fa198352b23bc4cbc9af45f7094f21baf25e766/Deployment/MintyBreeze/Templates/AVD/deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep

Comment: I figured how to upload the files I am working on...Here they are

https://github.com/isotonicuk/MyFilesShared

Comment: I have added the main.bicep file run with the parameters file. avd-environment.parameters.json

The module and parameter files which build the session hosts are:

https://github.com/isotonicuk/MyFilesShared/blob/main/deploy-avd-sessionhosts.bicep
https://github.com/isotonicuk/MyFilesShared/blob/main/avd-sessionhost.parameters.json

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve in the end. I needed to add features into the `deploy-shared-image-gallery.bicep` file:

```
features: [
{
name: 'SecurityType'
value: 'TrustedLaunch'
}
]
```

At the point when it creates the resource `galleryDefinition`, after it declares the `hyperVGeneration`. What I found is it's not well documented at the moment.